# Invoke built-in command from VSTS extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible to invoke a built-in VSTS command from a custom extension?

I develop an [extension with customized test results tab](https://github.com/Oriflame/VSTSTestResultExtension), and I want to reuse some built-in VSTS functionality. For example invoke *Create bug* menu action to create a new bug work item for a given test result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to use its API or call REST API:

[Client APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=vsts)

Comment: I thought it was impossible. So I would have to recreate a lot of functionality.